# Where are the Wazirs?

Tags: strategy, chess

A wazir is a fairy chess piece that moves like a rook, but can go only one square.

> [image]

We wish to place a number of wazirs on a **9 $\times$ 9** chessboard so the following conditions are satisfied

> 1. Each wazir is being attacked by at least one other wazir.
> 2. Each empty square is being attacked by at least one wazir.

**What is the minimum number of wazirs we need to place to satisfy the conditions above?**

Comment: I've been wanting to do chess riddles for a while now, but what program do you guys use to make the chess board and place pieces and everything?

Comment: @PotatoLatte Try this: https://www.chess.com/analysis

Comment: https://lichess.org/editor allows to set up a position, and, if you click on "Analysis Board" you can also insert moves and link to the game.

Comment: (+1) Any reason why you chose the name wazir?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wazir_%28chess%29 :)

Comment: Hah, *wazir*. That's a funny name :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have a solution with

> 25 wazirs:
>  [image]

Step by step:

> We can cover all border squares with 8 pairs of wazirs whose attacking squares do not overlap. Note that each wazir covers two border squares, which is the maximum because it's not possible for a piece to be orthogonally adjacent to 3 border squares on a 9x9 board. So there is no way to cover the entire border with fewer wazirs.
>  [image]
>
>  Also note that this arrangement covers the maximum amount of non-border squares as well. Every wazir covering two border squares covers exactly one non-border square, unless it is located one step diagonally from a corner (in which it covers 2). Every square one step diagonally from a corner is in use, so the wazirs cover the maximum possible amount of non-border squares.
>
>  There are 17 dark squares left, so we need a minimum of 5 wazirs to cover them all.
>  [image]
>
>  Then we need four more wazirs to cover the remaining 12 light squares.
>  [image]

Comment: What a pity you have to break the symmetry with that one piece, as you can't put it in the centre. Lovely solution though.

Comment: this is minimal :)

Comment: Very nice argument, I like the diagrams. I was hoping somebody would be able to present something like this.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an attempt which needs

> 27

wazirs:

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

A perhaps more elegant way to do

> 27 wazirs

than @Glorfindel's solution is:

> Put wazirs on every square on the b, e, and h files. Alternatively, the 2nd, 5th, and 8th rank. You get the idea.