# How to fully tile an 8 by 8 square with Z-tetrominoes?

Tags: tiling, polyomino

Is it possible to fully tile an 8 by 8 square grid using only Z-tetrominoes? (I don't know the answer...)

Answer (score 20):

If reflections are not allowed:

> It's impossible.

The figures below show why.

> Concentrate on one of the corners of the square. There are two orientations of the z tetromino (assuming no reflection), and only one of these orientations can fill the corner, shown below.
>
>  [image: z tetrominos on the corner]
>
>  Now note that in the valid configuration, the square marked 'A' is impossible to fill. Therefore, the 8x8 grid can't be tiled.

If reflections are allowed:

> It is still impossible.

See figure below showing the top three rows of the 8x8 square.

> [image: top row argument]
>
>  The red tetromino is placed without loss of generality (from the argument above, rotations/reflections won't help). The only way to cover the cell marked 'B' is with the yellow tetromino, and similarly for the orange tetromino over 'C'. It is then impossible to fill cell 'D'.

Comment: The question specifies $8 \times 8$, not $4 \times 4$.

Comment: @RobPratt yes, but the same argument is going to hold if the grid is expanded downward and leftward.

Comment: I agree, but the statement that A cannot be covered is false.  Note that I'm assuming that Z can be both rotated and flipped.

Comment: @RobPratt see edit, pretty sure the answer doesn't change.

Comment: Looks better now.

Comment: @RobPratt I would not expect reflection to be allowed: a reflected Z-tetromino is an S-tetromino, that is, a different tetromino entirely. Also, _Tetris_ allows rotation, but not reflection (which is why each reflection of those tetrominoes where it makes a difference are considered separate tetrominoes); _Tetris_ may not have a monopoly on tetrominoes by any means, but the terminology in use here comes from it, so...

Comment: As @KRyan says, the question specifically mentions _Z_-tetraminoes – but this answer uses S-tetraminoes in the illustrations. Not that that changes anything about the answer, of course.

Answer (score 18):

> Here's a "coloring" proof of impossibility.

\begin{matrix}
9 &1 &9 &5 &5 &9 &1 &9 \\
1 &-11 &-3 &-7 &-7 &-3 &-11 &1 \\
9 &-3 &5 &1 &1 &5 &-3 &9 \\
5 &-7 &1 &-3 &-3 &1 &-7 &5 \\
5 &-7 &1 &-3 &-3 &1 &-7 &5 \\
9 &-3 &5 &1 &1 &5 &-3 &9 \\
1 &-11 &-3 &-7 &-7 &-3 &-11 &1 \\
9 &1 &9 &5 &5 &9 &1 &9 
\end{matrix}

The sum of the matrix entries is $48$, but each possible placement of a Z-tetromino covers a nonpositive sum ($0$, $-4$, or $-8$).

Comment: Cool graph.  How did you discover it?  Does it generalize?

Comment: Thanks. It arises from linear programming dual variables, which provide a general approach for certifying infeasibility of linear systems of equalities and inequalities.  For another example, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4354682/help-with-colouring-proof-for-tiling-a-3x9-board-with-l-dominos/4354706#4354706

Answer (score 5):

Answer:

> If the chessboard edges loop into each other (like a torus): [image: you can].

Comment: One could argue that “square” implies boundaries, but I’m a fan of the lateral thinking here.